# Where can I inject a little singularity into the MVC display text?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Call me a grammar nerd, but it irritates me inordinately (no pun intended) when a results label says "1 results found" -- IOW, when it displays the plural for a singular situation (BTW, why are "0" results considered plural/multiple?).

So, I'm trying to add code to deal with that special case in an asp.net MVC site/app.

Here is the pertinent (I think) code:

HTML/RAZOR:

```
<td id="tdNumberOfResults" colspan="3" style="font-size: 13px; padding-top: 32px; text-align: right; visibility: hidden;">
    <span id="spanNumberOfResults" style="display: none; position: relative; right: 5px;">
        @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.NumberOfResults)
    </span>
```

jQuery:

```
        var resultsText = jQuery.trim($("#spanNumberOfResults").text());

        if (resultsText != "") {
            $("#tdNumberOfResults").css("visibility", "visible");

            // adding this to singularize "results" to "result" when 1 is the amount doesn't work
//                if (resultsText == "1 results") {
//                    resultsText = "1 result";
//                }
    . . .
```

C#/RAZOR:

```
namespace DBPReporter.Models
{
    public class DBPSalesReceiptCriteriaModel : ReportModelCore
    {
        [LocalizedDisplayName("NumberOfResults", NameResourceType = typeof(FieldNames.FieldNames))]
        public long? NumberOfResults { get; set; }
    . . .
```

I realize the advantage of MVC and suchlike, but all the abstraction/indirection/misdirection is sometimes frustrating. At times I yearn for the days of yore when programming was "closer to the metal" so to speak. Of course, the days of my yore differ from the days of your yore, geschweige denn those of Eeyore.

### UPDATE

As retribution for my obsession with precise grammar, the browser gave me this comeuppance akin to a swift slap:

```
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Section blocks ("@section Header { ... }") cannot be nested.  Only one level of section blocks are allowed.  

Source Error:     

Line 203:}
Line 204:
Line 205:@section MainHead
Line 206:{
Line 207:    @*<link type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" />*@

Source File: /DBPReporter/Views/DBPCriteria/ReceiptCriteria.cshtml    Line: 205 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

...when I altered the code to this:

```
//alert(resultsText); <-- just "1" !?
if (resultsText.trim == "1") {
    $("#spanNumberOfResults").text("1 result");
}
```

It's as if I petted the cat, and the dog bit me.

### UPDATE 2

Alright, the above is some sort of haywire brace mismatch or syntax error or something, but once I get that worked out, I think I have the solution: I change code in the Controller, namely from agreeably spartan but disappointingly one-dimensional line:

```
model.message = String.Format("{0} results", result.Count);
```

...to this:

```
if (result.Count == 1)
{
    model.message = String.Format("{0} result", result.Count);
}
else
{
    model.message = String.Format("{0} results", result.Count);
}
```

### UPDATE 3

A funny thing happened on the way to the compilation:

I tried to format the document, and it complained that it couldn't do it, because of this line:

```
<span style="background-color: #e55302; color: hsla(360, 100%, 100%, 1); font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, sans-serif; display: inline-block; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px; position: relative; right: 0px; width: 300px;" >
```

I then removed "Segoe UI", tried again, and it complied with the reformatting of the document. BUT...it "minified" my code! I ended up with:

```
$("#FormSalesTotalMin, #FormSalesTotalMax").autoNumeric( { mNum: 5, mDec: 2, aNeg:
'', aSep: ',' }); $("#FormDeptBegin, #FormDeptEnd").autoNumeric( { mNum: 5, mDec:
0, aNeg: '', aSep: '' }); $("#PasteUPCs").click(function(e) { if (jQuery.trim($("#PasteUPCs").val())
== "") $("#PasteUPCs").val(""); }); $("#submit_button").click(function() { $("#tdNumberOfResults").css("visibility",
```

(etc.)

Thanks to Ctrl+Z, that self-sardinizing was only momentary, but still I sometimes wonder if Visual Studio is "over-medicated."

### UPDATE 4

Henrique is on the right track. But here's what the feedback used to look like:

[image]

...and here's what it looks like now:

[image: too squishy, and too secretive]

Comment: Does `NumberOfResults` include the label?

Comment: I really would like to upvote this question solely for your choice(s?) of word, yet it seems to be a bit too localized and unlikely to help future visitors. Especially "UPDATE 4", which just shows two pieces of rendered HTML and CSS, without aforementioned HTML and CSS being present in your question. Besides that, changing a question's subject until all related issues are resolved makes earlier answers a bit irrelevant. Can you perhaps re-edit the question to only show the currently relevant information, and ask one question per problem you encounter (but not before researching it yourself)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how the code

```
@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.NumberOfResults)
```

is generating the whole string "1 results found" once the NumberOfResults property is a long, so I'll assume its contains only the number.

You can add some logic in the Razor view to produce the right pluralization using a conditional expression:

```
<td id="tdNumberOfResults" colspan="3" style="font-size: 13px; padding-top: 32px; text-align: right;">
    <span id="spanNumberOfResults" >
        @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.NumberOfResults) @(Model.NumberOfResults > 1 ? "results" : "result") found.
    </span>
</td>
```

In this case you don't have to handle the pluralization on the client side with jquery.

Comment: With that (after changing "Numer" to "Number"), I get nothing at all, tex-wise: just my orange-ish background...

Comment: The inline style with "display:none" was causing the problem. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that "display:none" either; there is no documentation or comments, and the original developers are in (or should be in) Belview now, so I don't know what the thinking was behind that. I'm updating my post with gorgeous images of how it all looks (then and now).

Answer (score 1):

Just change your jquery to:

```
var results = $("#spanNumberOfResults").text();
if(results == "1 results")
    $("#spanNumberOfResults").text("1 result");
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6VEn/).

Your `resultsText` is a string object not a jQuery reference, so you need to set the `Text` value of the jQuery element to the new text, not just change the var.

Comment: That makes all the sense in the world, yet I still get "1 results"

Comment: When you can alter the server-side code, just do that. Deliberately sending wrong data to clients and then telling them to fix it, is a bit unnecessary.

Comment: @ClayShannon are you running the jquery before the page loads? try putting it on the bottom of the page, or wrapping in the jquery 'ready' function.